# Are there any guidelines to android landing screen menu icons?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm working on an app that currently just uses a listview for a menu, but have decided to change it and create a landing screen like the ones described in this article:
[What Android Apps Should Look like?](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/12/how-should-android-apps-look-like_16.html)

Does anyone have some guidelines in creating icons for these menu items?
I have created custom button graphics in the past, but wanted them to look like pixel art, and when put in android, they became stretched and blurred. So I plan to use different density resources as a solution. Will it work the same as the launcher icon guidelines on the android website? Should they all be the same sizes as the guidelines even though we're talking about items on a screen? 
that is..
36 x 36 px(120 dpi) 48 x 48 px(160) 72 x 72 px(240) 96 x 96 px(320)

My app will have 4 choices on the landing page. Any advice or tips would be much appreciated. I did a search but just kept coming across launcher icon questions.

Comment: BTW I'm trying to keep away from stretching the images in any way to prevent artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
>   should follow the **3:4:6:8** scaling ratio between the four generalized
>   densities.

I got this from the documentation under "Alternative drawables"
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer this api [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have already gone over that doc. Do you think I should use the same resolution and density properties to create my landing screen icons?